# Gradle:Can I use a flatDir repository to include sources and/or javadocs?

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ and Gradle.

I'm not exactly experienced with Gradle. I've built JCEF on my computer, and using flatDir to include the actual class jar is easy. However, I would like to include source code for JCEF. I'm currently just going into IntelliJ and including the sources through there. Is there a way to declare my source jar using Gradle?

Comment: Check out [this thread](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-supply-source-jars-from-flatdir-for-eclipse-debugging/35670). As described there, you need to create a `maven` repository on the local file system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to create a local Maven repository to put these libraries.
https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-supply-source-jars-from-flatdir-for-eclipse-debugging/35670